# Why derivatives appear in the form of gradients or divergence?

Tags: differentiation

There are many physics problems whose mathematical equations have the same form.

At these problems we always get an equation with a gradient. And the derivatives appear in the form of a gradient or a divergence.

What are the reasons benind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient is a fancy word for derivative, or the rate of change of a function. It’s a vector (a direction to move) that

1. Points in the direction of greatest increase of a function (intuition on why)
2. Is zero at a local maximum or local minimum (because there is no single direction of increase)

The term "gradient" is typically used for functions with several inputs and a single output (a scalar field). Yes, you can say a line has a gradient (its slope), but using "gradient" for single-variable functions is unnecessarily confusing for Physicists (my opinion!).

Answer (score 2):

Because there are three indistinguishable spatial dimensions and the three partial derivatives need to enter into physics equations in a way that doesn’t distinguish changes in one direction from changes in the other directions.

Another way of saying this is that $\partial/\partial x$, $\partial/\partial y$, and $\partial/\partial x$ only make sense in isotropic 3D space when combined into the *vector* operator $\vec{\nabla}$, which is then used to form the gradient, the divergence, and the curl.